# Map/Reduce location status updater

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

My mapred-site-xml:

```
 mapreduce.framework.name yarn
 mapred.job.tracker localhost:9001
```

My core-site-xml:

```
fs.defaultFS 
hdfs://localhost:9000
hadoop.tmp.dir  
file:/opt/hadoop
```

Nn eclipse map/reduce master:

```
localhost 9001 
dfs master: 9000
```

Finally it appeared:

> An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status
>   updater". org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf

[image]

Comment: is there an exception you can show?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: image of text isn't helping

Comment: what should be showed  in my question?(i'm a rookie.)